# How to get name of active calendar folder?

Tags: exchangewebservices

I'm building a calendar synchronization that syncs external appointments to Exchange calendars.

I have some Danish Exchange accounts that have two calendar folders, named "Calendar" and "Kalender". I suppose there could be a "Calendario" folder for Spanish users, too. It seems that sometimes the English-named calendar is shown to other users, and sometimes the localized calendar is shown, both to the user and to other users viewing the shared calendar. I suspect this has to do with the regional settings of the user combined with the "Rename default folders so their names match the specified language" setting.

Is there some way to get the "active" calendar folder of a user via (unmanaged) EWS? The only other solution I can think of is to sync appointments to all the calendar-like folder names I encounter.

Comment: Doesn't the DistInguishedFolderId "calendar" give you the right folder? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580808

Comment: Actually, yes it does. A couple accounts claim they have no DistInguishedFolderId 'calendar', but still have one or more calendar folders. But maybe they are just horribly broken. I can work around that.

Comment: @ErikCederstrand, how did you work around that? I am currently having the same problem

Comment: By using a list of known localized folder names (see https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/d556d7e6dc09f17a1ea917390ad7031c5dbc5de3/exchangelib/folders.py#L536). Default is to request the distinguished folder, else use the only calendar folder (assuming there's only one), and finally looking up the folder name in the list of localized names, as a last resort. I think the situation is caused by a horribly broken PowerShell localization script floating around on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jan Doggen noted, the correct thing to do is to just get DistInguishedFolderId "calendar".